# Add options to 'Add...' in Visual Studio 2012 Folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, plugins

I accidentally did a Windows 8 Refresh (DON'T EVER DO THAT!) and now after re-installing VS2012 I don't have as many options when I am adding new files.

Specifically when I right-clicked a folder before it gave me four options - JavaScript File, TypeScript file, HTML File, and something else.  Anyone have some direction on what plug-in or tool for VS2012 made this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be fixed after updating to the latest update of VS2012 and installing Web Essentials.